# File to import not found or unreadable: @material/button/mdc-button

Tags: angular, material-components, material-components-web

I use Angular v6.1.2 And just initial project following getting start guild. Then I add MDC following this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-components-web,

Then in my project at styles.scss file I just import MDC scss like this

```
@import "~material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

Then I run the application it shows me this error

> Module build failed: 
>       @import "@material/button/mdc-button";
>       ^
>          File to import not found or unreadable: @material/button/mdc-button.
>       and so on...

I've tried to add a path in `angular.json` like the code below but it doesn't work.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
        "./node_modules/material-components-web", "./node_modules/@material"
    ]
}
```

Is there anything else that I miss?

Comment: try importing  in styles.scss

Comment: Yep, I import it in styles.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Just include on `node_modules` path, because of `material-components-web` and `@material` need to know the parent path.